# How to use SQLServer SessionState database in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

My custom sessionstate database (SQL Server) is not being populated when the sessionstate configuration is setup in the Umbraco site web.config.

I think it is because Session_Start is not firing!?

Can anyone tell me how to implement Session_Start in Umbraco in Global.asax !? SQLServer session database not working..

SessionState Connectionstring is fine as it works on a blank web application so it must be how Umbraco handles Session_Start (or doesn't!)

I'm using Umbraco 6.1.2.

Thanks

-- Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh.. I found the solution here.. Thanks to the Umbraco community

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/46724-How-to-use-SQLServer-SessionState-database-in-Umbraco

My Global.asax was inheriting from the wrong thing! (I didn't write the code, just debugging it)

-- Lee